# If EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable1) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable2 where ...)

Tags: sql

I've a problem to properly do this transaction in SQL:

```
If exists(SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable1 table1) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable2 table2 where table2.id = table1.id)
BEGIN 
    SELECT......
END
ELSE.....
```

I try this too with no success:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable1)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM #tempTable1 table1
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable2 where id = table1.id)
    BEGIN
    .....
  END
END
ELSE....
```

Can you please tell me if there is a good method to do this?

Comment: And what should be the logic behind that in your words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you want:

```
If EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable1 table1 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #tempTable2 table2 
                                WHERE table2.id = table1.id))

BEGIN
..
END
```

Returns true if there are rows in Table1 which do not exists in Table2

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47cb0/3)**